# Cannot activate virtual environment in VSCode, despite updated ExecutionPolicy

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, python-venv, executionpolicy

I am trying to set up a virtual environment in VSCode.

For this I have created a folder 'newproject' using `-m venv newproject` in GitBash.

The problem is that I cannot activate the virtual environment because running scripts
is disabled on this system (below code is from the VSCode terminal):

```
./activate : File C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Dokumente\py_scripts\newproject\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For      
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./activate
./activate : File C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Dokumente\py_scripts\newproject\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For      
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I find this confusing, because I have tried setting the execution policies as admin via Powershell to both RemoteSigned and Unrestricted but I still get the error (below code is from PowerShell):

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): y
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process    RemoteSigned
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine       Undefined


PS C:\windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): y
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process    Unrestricted
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine       Undefined
```

Why do I still receive the error despite allowing locally written Scripts to be run?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you already install the virtualenv??

Comment: Yes, the 'newproject' folder has  all files created in it:
`name@DESKTOP-EIQBST8 MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Dokumente/py_scripts/newproject
$ dir
Include  Lib  Scripts  pyvenv.cfg`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.
One has to allow scripts within VSCode and not in a separate PowerShell window:

```
PS C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Dokumente\py_scripts\newproject\Scripts> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process
PS C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Dokumente\py_scripts\newproject\Scripts> ./activate
(newproject) PS C:\Users\mikes\OneDrive\Dokumente\py_scripts\newproject\Scripts>
```